# My nextJs application gives "404 requested path could find" error on deployment. Even though deployment is successfull

Tags: next.js, deployment, gitlab

these are screenshots and files-[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bssnb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ9Wx.png)

this is dev-ci.yml file :

```
image: node:18.19-bullseye
stages:
  # - lint
  - build
  - deploy

# lint:
  # stage: lint
  # before_script:
    # - echo "Start CI/CD"
    # - yarn install
#  script:
#    - yarn lint

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting the Build"
    - mv ./src/config/env.json ./src/config/env.json.old
    - mv ./src/config/dev.env.json ./src/config/env.json
  script:
    - yarn install
    - CI=false yarn build
    - touch pcc-app.tar.bz2
    - tar --exclude='./node_modules' --exclude='./.github' --exclude='pcc-app.tar.bz2' -jcvf pcc-app.tar.bz2 ./
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pcc-app.tar.bz2
    expire_in: 1 week

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$ENC_NP_DEPLOY_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan qa.enc.systems >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  when: on_success
  script:
    - scp pcc-app.tar.bz2 apyadmin@qa.enc.systems:/home/apyadmin/artifacts/enc/dev
    - ssh apyadmin@qa.enc.systems <<'ENDSSH'
    - cd /home/apyadmin/apps/enc/dev
    - rm -rf ./web-pcc
    - mkdir ./web-pcc
    - tar -jxvf /home/apyadmin/artifacts/enc/dev/pcc-app.tar.bz2 --directory ./web-pcc
    - sudo systemctl restart dev-enc-pcc
    - ENDSSH
    - echo "Deployed Successfully"

after_script:
  - echo "End CI/CD"
```

next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I want it to run as it is working fine on local when i run yarn build and yarn start. It is working fine on  local when i run yarn build and yarn start but not working on deployment server. although build and stages are shown successfull but the site is only showing 404 not found error.